# How to close sql server connection on completion when using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using the Sql Server powershell snapins (i.e. "SqlServerProviderSnapin100", "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100").  I execute scripts using powershell, but when I try to execute them again, I get a "No process is on the other end of the pipe" shared memory error.  I need to close Powershell, and restart it before it will work again.

It appears that powershell is keeping a connection open, which is preventing the reexecution of the scripts.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally any open connection has to be closed or dispose. So look for methods with this names. I don't know this snapins, so cannot be more concrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

The problem: The ADO connection pool is holding the connection once it is opened.  Sql Server closes the connections, but the pool does not know of this, consequently, ADO assumes the connection is still valid, but it is not.

The solution: Execute [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools() first.  This invalidates all connections that ADO is currently holding in the pool, and prevents the exception.